# Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash and preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code :

```
$string1 = "My name is 'Kate' and im fine"; 
$pattern = "My name is '(.*)' and im fine"; 
preg_match($pattern , $string1, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

and when im run it returns this error:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: As a note that may be helpful to others, if you are passing all your arguments to `preg_match()` as variables, make sure you don't get the order of the variables accidentally mixed up in the function call as this will also almost certainly result in this same error appearing.

Comment: You need a delimiter in your regexp string

Comment: Use `$pattern = "/My name is '(.*)' and im fine/";`

Answer (score 162):

You need a delimiter for your pattern.  It should be added at the start and end of the pattern like so:

```
$pattern = "/My name is '(.*)' and im fine/";  // With / as a delimeter
```

Comment: Beware of using double quotes to encase regex expressions, otherwise some \+character combinations (such as `\l` for line feed) will be converted to their character, which may well produce an expression other than expected. Use single quotes. See [php Strings description](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: In this example the string includes singles quotes so it is easier to use double quotes to enclose it (avoiding the escaping `\'` that would be require if it was enclosed in single quotes).

Comment: I was making a general comment, as people viewing examples may take them as something to 'cookie-cut' for themselves, not realising the unforeseen consequences that may happen if they extend it to other situations. Unfortunately, I cannot change my comment to be even more specific.

Answer (score 87):

The solution (which other answers don't mention—at least at the time of my originally writing this) is that when PHP refers to delimiters, it's not referring to the delimiters you see in your code (which are quote marks) but the next characters inside the string.  (In fact I've never seen this stated anywhere in any documentation: you have to see it in examples.)  So instead of having a regular expression syntax like what you may be accustomed to from many other languages:

```
/something/
```

PHP uses strings, and then looks inside the string for ***another*** delimiter:

```
'/something/'
```

The delimiter PHP is referring to is the pair of `/` characters, instead of the pair of `'` characters.  So if you write `'something'`, PHP will take `s` as the intended delimiter and complain that you're not allowed to use alphanumeric characters as your delimiter.

So if you want to pass (for instance) an `i` to show that you want a case-insensitve match, you pass it inside the string but outside of the regex delimiters:

```
'/something/i'
```

If you want to use something other than `/` as your delimiter, you can, such as if you're matching a URL and don't want to have to escape all the slashes:

```
'~something~'
```

Comment: @Gruber: thanks!  you can always send all your friends links to it and let them upvote it ;)

Comment: Explaning what documentation doesn't explain.. +1 Thank you!

Comment: The highest upvoted answer is the same as this, however, I am grateful to now understand *why* this is the correct answer. +1 Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You must specify a delimiter for your expression. A delimiter is a special character used at the start and end of your expression to denote which part is the expression. This allows you to use modifiers and the interpreter to know which is an expression and which are modifiers. As the error message states, the delimiter cannot be a backslash because the backslash is the escape character.

```
$pattern = "/My name is '(.*)' and im fine/";
```

and below the same example but with the `i` modifier to match without being case sensitive.

```
$pattern = "/My name is '(.*)' and im fine/i";
```

As you can see, the `i` is outside of the slashes and therefore is interpreted as a modifier.

Also bear in mind that if you use a forward slash character (/) as a delimiter you must then escape further uses of / in the regular expression, if present.

Answer (score 8):

The pattern must have delimiters. Delimiters can be a forward slash (/) or any non alphanumeric characters(#,$,*,...). Examples

```
$pattern = "/My name is '(.*)' and im fine/"; 
$pattern = "#My name is '(.*)' and im fine#";
$pattern = "@My name is '(.*)' and im fine@";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not related to original code example, but I received the error "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" and Googled here.
Reason: I mixed order of parameters for preg_match. Pattern was the second parameter and string to match was first. Be careful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com) which has [automatic delimiters](https://t-regx.com/docs/delimiters) for you:

```
$matches = pattern("My name is '(.*)' and im fine")->match($string1)->all();

                 // ↑ No delimiters needed
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you get the same error when you pass arguments to `preg_match` in the wrong order. Make sure that you're passing arguments in the following order , where only the first two are required:

```
preg_match($regex_pattern, $string_to_search, $matches, $flags, $offset);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try with this

```
$pattern = "/My name is '\(.*\)' and im fine/";
```

Comment: Why escape parentheses ?

Comment: @kiJey. In the OP's situation, they wanted to extract the name, so the parentheses are required for the match, and therefore must NOT be escaped. This is why I'm downvoting it.