# PHP retrieve text value from custom tags with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, custom-tag

Hi people I have searched the php website for a fast and simple solution, I searched also on google but nothing that I find seams to work.

```
preg_match("/\[video-code\](.*?)\[\/video-code\]/", the_content(), $match);
echo "result=".$match[1];
```

I am trying to get the text in between these to tags "[video-code]...[/video-code]"
Is there anybody who can help me out whit probably this small issue? I tried different things but it seams I am doing something wrong!?

Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'¬\[BeginingOfTag](.*?)\[/EndOfTag]¬is'`

I have this pattern on use on a majority of my sites, I've used it in preg_match in the past but mostly in use for preg_replace.. So give it a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: I get this error in the browser when I try this, I am using it in combination with wordpress maybe that's a issue!?

<b>Warning</b>
: preg_replace() [
<a href="function.preg-replace">function.preg-replace</a>
]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in
<b>/home/test/domains/test.nl/public_html/test/wp-content/themes/test/overlay-samen-trots.php</b>
on line
<b>21</b>
<br>
result=

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660545/delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-and-preg-match

Comment: Ok I figured it out, it had to do with Wordpress. Wordpress 'the_content()' is in a certain way formatted. It doesn't see it as text is my best guess. So instead of 'the_content()' I now used the $post->post_content and this worked perfect.