# preg_match() delimiter error (slightly different)

Tags: php, preg-match, delimiter

having a problem with a delimiter. I'm a noob with PHP, so I'm sorry if this is a really simple fix. I was using eregi() before, but I checked on here for a "deprecated" error, and I found out that I had to use preg_match. Anyways, here's the error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /home/legitstr/public_html/members/includes/functions.php on line 4
```

And here's my code: (I've checked on other threads before, but no one seems to have similar code to mine)

```
$file = basename(__FILE__);
if(preg_match($file,$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
die("Sorry but you cannot access this file directly for security reasons.");
```

Please help me out, and thank you!

Comment: You missed the part of code that's important here; the line. What that error means is that you need delimiters around your regex, so if it was `'regex'` now it has to be `'/regex/'`. PHP has some nice docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: Why not a simple `strpos` or `stripos` instead of `preg_match`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash and preg\_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660545/delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-and-preg-match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$file = basename(__FILE__);
if(false !== strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $file)) {
die("Sorry but you cannot access this file directly for security reasons.");
```

> strpos()

or

> stripos()

for case insensitive match, should be a better match for what you seem to be doing

Comment: I agree this is a better approach than regex. My answer addresses "how to make the error go away", but your answer addresses "the right way to solve this problem".

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your regex with delimiters - usually something like `/myregex/`

If you leave off the delimiters you get this error.  You could try

```
if(preg_match($file,"|".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."|")) {
```

Since `|` is a legitimate delimiter, and [may not be used in a legal URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/1967396)

Having said that - regex is a powerful tool, and if you are looking for a verbatim match it may be overkill. Furthermore, a URL could have all kinds of characters in it that have special meaning in regex - which would actually cause a false match. For example, `.` in a regex means "any character", so `apple.com` will match `applescom` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I'm getting this error: 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/legitstr/public_html/members/header.php on line 8

Comment: typo - missing a period in the string. Now fixed. Try again?

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll keep this fix in mind for future reference :)