# Comparing two strings using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I would like to search $string for occurrences of the contents of $array but am having trouble with the implode function returning the following:

> preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

So in the example below $string will be searched for 'Empire' or 'Jedi'.

This is almost certainly something to do with escaping but I can't get my head round it.

Many thanks

```
$string = 'The Empire Strikes back';
$array = array (
        0 => 'Empire',
        1 => 'Jedi'
);

if (preg_match( implode(" ", $array), $string )) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash and preg\_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660545/delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-and-preg-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex must have [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). What you want is `/Empire|Jedi/i` (read: “search for Empire or Jedi, case insensitive”).

Therefore, you must use it as follows:

```
...
preg_match('/' . implode("|", $array) . '/', $string)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct : implode("|", $array)

Cause | = OR

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'The Empire Strikes back';
$array = array (
        0 => 'Empire',
        1 => 'Jedi'
);

$re = join ('|', array_map('preg_quote', $array));
var_dump (preg_match ("/$re/", $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this:

```
 $Words = array('Empire', 'Jedi');
 $strings = 'The Empire Strikes back';
 foreach ($Words as $Word) {
 if (preg_match("/\b$Word\b/", $strings)) {
     echo "A match was found.";
   }
  else{
    echo "A match was not found.";
   }
  }
```