# Preg_replace Pattern Variable

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a list of names and I'm using preg_replace to make a certain part of those names bold. I was using str_replace but I needed a limit on it.

However I'm getting the error "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash". After some research I found out that it's happening because I'm missing slashes on my pattern variable.

However I've been trying and I can't get it right and I'm not finding any example like mine. Thank you for your help.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $name = $row['name'];

    $array = explode(' ',trim($name));
    $array_length = count($array);

    for ($i=0; $i<$array_length; $i++ ) {
        $letters = substr($array[$i], 0, $q_length);
        if ($letters = $q) {
        $bold_name = '<strong>'.$letters.'</strong>';
        $final_name = preg_replace($letters, $bold_name, $array[$i], 1);
        $array[$i] = $final_name; } 
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash and preg\_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660545/delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-and-preg-match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a delimiter on your regex. For example, using `~`:

```
$final_name = preg_replace('~'.$letters.'~', $bold_name, $array[$i], 1);
```

You can read more at [**the documentation for PCRE delimiters**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and [**the documentation for `preg_replace`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

From the docs:

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by *delimiters*. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (`/`), hash signs (`#`) and tildes (`~`). The following are all examples of valid delimited patterns.
>
> `/foo bar/`
>
> `#^[^0-9]$#`
>
> `+php+`
>
> `%[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%`

Comment: Oops. Copied and edited the wrong line. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very simple after all!

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add simple delimiter to first parameter of `preg_replace`.

Add forward slashes to your `$letters` (However other delimiters can be used also.)

```
$final_name = preg_replace('/'.$letters.'/', $bold_name, $array[$i], 1);
```

As you mentioned in question, answer is in itself that `Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`.