# Php replacing strings in html ouput

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to replace the first string in the code

```
$confirmation_message = apply_filters("pmpro_confirmation_message",  $confirmation_message, false);
    $confirmation_message = preg_replace('mysite.com', 'mysite.com?true', $str, 1);
    echo $confirmation_message;
```

But it is giving me a weird error

```
   Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash line
```

Here's the original output of $confirmation_message

```
   <p><font><font class="">Visit your new site here: </font></font><a href="mysite.com/"><font><font class="">mysite.com</font></font></a></p>

  <p><font><font class="">Manage your new site here: </font></font><a href="mysite.com/wp-admin/"><font><font class="">mysite.com/admin</font></font></a></p>
```

Comment: You have wrong regexp in preg_replace. `preg_replace('/mysite.com/', 'mysite.com?true', $str, 1);`

Comment: I tried that also, but that didn't worked @PiotrOlaszewski

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash and preg\_match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660545/delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-and-preg-match)

Comment: This is odd. Your string working fine for me with regexp like `/mysite.com/`

Comment: Yeah i got the errors
actually i didnt replaced $str with my variable ie with $confirmation_message @PiotrOlaszewski

Answer (score 1):

As @Piotr Olaszewski commented, you need to add the delimiters to the pattern.

```
$confirmation_message = preg_replace('/mysite\.com/', 'mysite.com?true', $confirmation_message, 1);
```

Note the escaped dot in the pattern as well.

Had you wanted to replace **all** occurrences of *mysite.com*, you could have used [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for better performance:

```
$confirmation_message = str_replace('mysite.com', 'mysite.com?true', $confirmation_message);
```

Comment: Author want replace only first occurrence of string, not all. str_replace change all found string.