# Why doesn't this regex work with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regex `/id=?\d*-\d*/` i tested it here [live demo](http://regexr.com/3eu1i)

but when i use this code for getting **id=3607-7**

```
$line = '[24/Oct/2016:11:20:57 +0200] "GET /ajax/magasins/initMagasin.php?id=3607-7 HTTP/1.1" 200 747 "https://asdjjhdsa.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50';
preg_match('id=?\d*-\d*', $line, $matches);
echo $matches[1] ."\n";
```

i have this warning

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660545/delimiter-must-not-be-alphanumeric-or-backslash-and-preg-match) 
and when i use

```
preg_match('/id=?\d*-\d*/', $line, $matches);
```

i have this notice

> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:

Comment: `preg_match('/id=?\d*-\d*/', $line, $matches);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i edited my question, your answer give me a notice

Comment: You malformed the string literal, use `$line = '[24/Oct/2016:11:20:57 +0200] "GET /ajax/magasins/initMagasin.php?id=3607-7 HTTP/1.1" 200 747 "https://asdjjhdsa.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50';`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/zjaf9f).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i had the same result when i used your $line

Comment: You have no capture groups so the 1 index will never be populated. `echo $matches[0] `.... or group the `id` part so `1` is the integer, `id=?(\d*-\d*)`

Comment: @chris85 YES, this is the answer, can you post it like an answer please?

Comment: I can't, the question is closed. It'll just live as a comment answer. The dup is correct for the original question.

Comment: In my demo above,  I used `print_r($matches[0]);` to show which exact group to print.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, the problem was matches[0], it was my fault, i didn't pay attention, thanks for your answer