# Regex to remove 2 lines that begin with a string, ends with another string, and contains a new line

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've googled and googled, and look at dozens of other answers but can't find anything that address removed TWO lines that begin with one string, and end with another, so am not including "what i've tried" because the dozen or so patterns don't even come close.

We've extracted text form PDF files, and all the links within the result appear in the output as two lines like this:

`[Link]
2017_07_11_RM_4b.pdf`

They *always* start with `[Link]`, and *always* end with `.pdf`.  They appear throughout the result, often many times in a row, then a block of text, and more links, and so on - as many as 200+ occurrences.  I'm trying to get the block of text *without* the occurrences of these two-line strings with a `preg_replace()` that presumably looks something like this:

`$newtext = preg_replace("/^[Link]*$/", "", $text);`

Any assistance is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it: `\[Link\][\s\S]*?\.pdf\s`

**Demonstration**: https://regex101.com/r/NCqWES/2/

**Explanation**:

- `[\s\S]` - This means that we're matching every whitespace or non-whitespace character, which in turn means that we're matching all possible characters, including the possbile line breaks and whitespaces that are separating the word `\[Link\]` from the word `\.pdf`.
- `*?` - This is a lazy quantifier, which will stop at the first occurence of the match.
- Finally, I included a `\s` at the end to remove the remaining line break, but you could suppress it as well.

**Update:**

This may also work as well: `\[Link\]\s\w+\.pdf\s`, giving you a little performance gain. [Click for demo](https://regex101.com/r/NCqWES/4/).

Comment: This is the only answer that works (the original pattern), BUT only on regex101.  In my PHP, I'm getting ` preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in `. Tried changing to forward slashes, but only the text following the last match is returned

Comment: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7660574/6882194 you should do it like this: `/\[Link\][\s\S]*?\.pdf\s/`. Or, using the alternative regex: `/\[Link\]\s\w+\.pdf\s/`.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you - one last clarification, I tried pdf|asx and it broke - (turns out there's an occasional asx link)  Can this work for multiple extensions?  If not i can work around it -  Thank  you again

Comment: You can add any number of filetypes to this regex. It should stay like this: `/\[Link\][\s\S]*?\.(pdf|asx)\s/`

Comment: Ah, forgot the () - that did it, THANKS again

Answer (score 0):

This expression (example at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iy3U9S/1)) uses the [multiline pattern modifier](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) which changes `^` to match the start of every line instead of the start of the string.

```
/(?:^\[Link\]\n[^\n]*+\n)++/m

$newtext = preg_replace("/(?:^\[Link\]\n[^\n]*+\n)++/m", "", $text);
```

Additional notes

- We are using [possessive](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) quantifiers to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: So does this simply remove "two" lines, or how does the trailing '.pdf' get considered?

Comment: You are right, I missed the `.pdf` is that good enough or can you work from there on your own or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Going to try it now, just wanted that clarification before I started the hair pulling, thanks.  Should be able to accept your answer shortly, assuming all goes well.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
/^\[Link\]\s*(\w+)\.pdf$/m
```

Here you're looking for a multi line text where it begins with `[Link]` (in this case `[` and `]` are literal that's why the backslash) followed by an empty space `\s`, in your case a new line, and then any amount of letters, numbers and underscores, with a `.pdf` at the end of the string.

It's important to notice that this is going to create a catch group for your desired text, hence in your `preg_replace` you should now do something like:

```
$newtext = preg_replace("/^\[Link\]\s*(\w+)\.pdf$/m", "$1", $text);
```

Comment: `(?:)` prevents the capturing group.

Comment: I'm not preventing it purposely. The group is exactly what he needs in order to get the desired output.

Comment: We don't need group at all and your regex doesn't match filenames with special character.

Comment: If there are special characters in you filename you can simply replace `(\w+)` by `(.+?)` like this: `/^\[Link\]\s*(.+?)\.pdf$/m`. Also the group is only used to ease the capturing of the desired text removing all the undesired text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = <<<EOD
line1
[Link]
2017_07_11_RM_4b.pdf
line2
[Link]
2017_07_11_RM_4b.pdf
line3
EOD;
$newtext = preg_replace("/\[Link\]\R.+\.pdf\R/", "", $str);;
echo $newtext,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
line1
line2
line3
```

**Explanation:**

```
  \[Link\]  : literally [link]
  \R        : any kind of linebreak
  .+        : 1 or more any character but newline
  \.        : a dot
  pdf       : literally pdf
  \R        : any kind of linebreak
```